# How can we composite two piecewise functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let say
$$f(x) := \left\{\begin{array}{l l}x+1 & \text{ if } -2\leq x<0 \\ x-1 & \text{ if }0\leq x\leq 2\end{array}\right.$$ 
How can we find out $f\circ f$?

Comment: What have you tried? The result will generally be a piece-wise function with several pieces. If $x < -1$, what can you say about $f(x)$? What can you say about $f(f(x))$ then? And just to get started, what's the domain of $f \circ f$?

Comment: What I have tried is just $$f\circ f := \left\{\begin{array}{l l}(x+1)+1 & \text{ if } -2\leq x<0 \\ (x-1)-1 & \text{ if }0\leq x\leq 2\end{array}\right.$$. But I don't know how to determine the new intervals. If $x<-1$, $f(x)=x+1$, isn't it? But why $x<-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** First, verify that $f(x) \subset [-2,2]$ to be sure that the composition $f \circ f$ is well defined. Then you should carefully separate the cases. Here's an example for the first steps:

If $-2 \leq x < 0$ then $f(x) = x+1$ and so $f(x) < 0$ for $-2 \leq x < -1$, it follows that $f\circ f(x) = ((x+1)+1)$ for $-2 \leq x < -1$. Now if $-2 \leq x < 0$ then $f(x) = x+1$ and so $f(x) \geq 0$ for $-1 \leq x < 0$ thus ... Can you continue from here?

**EDIT:** To be more precise, let $y = f(x)$, then

$$f \circ f(x) = f(y) = \left\{\begin{array}{l l}y+1 & \text{ if } -2\leq y<0 \\ y-1 & \text{ if }0\leq y\leq 2\end{array}\right.=\left\{\begin{array}{l l}f(x)+1 & \text{ if } -2\leq f(x)<0 \\ f(x)-1 & \text{ if }0\leq f(x)\leq 2\end{array}\right.$$
So we have to separate the cases when $-2\leq f(x)<0$ and $0\leq f(x)\leq 2$. By definition of $f$ we know that $f(x) < 0$ for every $x \in [-2,-1)$ and $x \in [0,1)$. In particular this implies that if $x \in [-2,-1)$, then $f(x) = x+1 < 0$ and thus
$$f \circ f(x) = f(x)+1 = (x+1)+1 = x+2.$$
Stays to study the case $x \in [0,1)$ and $f(x) \geq 0$.

Comment: Sorry,I don't quite understand why the interval changes from $-2 \leq x < 0$ to $-2 \leq x < -1$. Actually my main concern is that how can we determine the new intervals of the new function

Comment: @Jacky I edited, is it more clear to you know?

Comment: This is my new attempt:
$$f \circ f(x) := \left\{\begin{array}{l l}x+2 & \text{ if } -2\leq x<-1 \\ x & \text{ if }-1\leq x<1\ \\x-2 &\text{ if } 1\leq x \leq 2 \end{array}\right.$$

Comment: @Jacky It's correct :), seems that you got it.

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The first thing to do is to write down the domain and codomain of your function. Here we have:
\begin{equation}
f:[-2,2]\longrightarrow[-1,1]
\end{equation}
Next, since $[-1,1]\subset[-2,2]$, it is OK to compose $f$ with itself. Try to figure out yourself what $f\circ f$ does.