# Composite function of a multiple condition function.

Tags: calculus, functions

**Q.** $f\left(x\right)=1+x\:for\:0\le x\le 2$

$f\left(x\right)=3-x\:for\:2<x\le 3$

Determine $g\left(x\right)=fof=f\left(f\left(x\right)\right)$.

Am a bit confused with the domain and range of g(x), can anyone explain the answer.

Comment: Have a look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932278/how-can-we-composite-two-piecewise-functions/932295#932295

Comment: Thanks for the link Surb. And great answer.:D

Comment: I just want to know: In the above case we even consider $fof=3-\left(1+x\right)$ in the domain $2<x\le 3$ and we also consider $fof=1+\left(3-x\right)$ in the domain $0\le x\le 2$. Is this because in case of fof the 'x' are replaced by 'f(x)'?

Comment: If I understand you well, yes. In your case, you'll have to consider the cases:
a) $0 \leq x \leq 2$ and $0 \leq f(x) \leq 2$, 
b) $0 \leq x \leq 2$ and $2 < f(x) \leq 3$,
c) $2 < x \leq 3$ and $0 \leq f(x) \leq 2$,
d) $2 < x \leq 3$ and $2 < f(x) \leq 3$.
And look in each of these case what is $f \circ f$.