# How to alter the interval of a composite function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Let $f, g : R → R$

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
    x + 3  &\text{if } x ≥ 0,\\
   x^2 &\text{if }  x < 0
  \end{cases}$$

$$g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
    2x + 1  &\text{if } x ≥ 3,\\
   x &\text{if }  x < 3
  \end{cases}$$

They asked us to calculate :
g ◦ f and f ◦ g. I did this, but i don't know how to write the intervals. Like i got

$$g ◦ f =  
\begin{cases}
    2x + 7  \\
   x^2 \\
   2x^2+1
  \end{cases}$$

and likewise

$$f ◦ g = 
\begin{cases}
    2x+4\\
   x+3\\
    x^2
  \end{cases}$$

but i don't know what conditions each of these results should be for x. like is x ≥ 0 or what? and how do i figure this out, is there a rule?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932278/how-can-we-composite-two-piecewise-functions/932295#932295

Answer (score 1):

You want to intersect the intervals.

For $f$ you have $(-\infty ,0)$ and $[0,\infty)$

For $g$ you have $(-\infty,3)$ and $[3,\infty)$

So, for the compositions, you want to look at each of the intervals $(-\infty,0)$,$[0,3)$, and $[3,\infty)$.